# Кликнуть на PictureBox и в месте, где мы кликнули должен появиться TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

При клике на `toolStripButton` мы выбираем, что нужно печатать текст. Далее нужно кликнуть на `PictureBox` и в месте, где мы кликнули должен появиться `TextBox`, в нем мы печатаем текст, после чего, он рисуется ниже при помощи `DrawString`. Не получается реализовать `TextBox` при клике, чтоб он появлялся. Он создается, но оказывается под `PictureBox`, его даже не видно.

```
TextBox tx = new TextBox();
tx.Name = "tools";
tx.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
tx.Size = new Size(150, 150);
tx.Text = "";
this.Controls.Add(tx);
```

[image: C# programm demo]

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй

```
tx.BringToFront();
```

И следите, чтобы контрол был добавлен в нужный контейнер.

Comment: Не понял, за что минус. Не поленился, создал тестовый проект и "BringToFront" помогло. Ну а коментарий по поводу нужного контейнера -  может у него PictureBox во вложенной панели, тогда "this.Controls.Add(tx)" было бы критическим местом.

Comment: Не знаю кто поставил минус, я вот плюс поставил)

Comment: Вроде ваше решение мне подходит, но не работает, посмотрите пожалуйста мой проект, вот ссылка https://yadi.sk/d/oacEvxamkVhiW

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: "tx.BringToFront()" в нужном месте? ;)